# RedPoint DataManagement

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Can any one help me with [RedPoint DM](http://www.redpoint.net/)?

I looking for how to create a variable which calls the `environment_sys` table and load a file into table using redpoint DM.

Any Videos , links are very helpful.

Thank You,
Swathi.

Comment: Are you actually using SQL Azure? 
What file are you looking to load in?

Comment: What table are you trying to load into? What format is the data in?